# plotly express sunburst segment color control

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a set of data like this which is vended from a database:

```
xdata = [
    ["ZT","Met",1],
    ["ZT","Compensates",0],
    ["ZT","Planned",0],
    ["ZT","To Do",0],

    ["ZT Basic","Met",6],
    ["ZT Basic","Compensates",6],
    ["ZT Basic","Planned",2],
    ["ZT Basic","To Do",1],

   ...
```

I wish to construct a sunburst with a white hole and where the level 1 ring (`xdata[n][0]` above) colors are picked from a suitably large palette but the level 2 segments ('Met','Planned', etc.) are always the same for each value, e.g. `Met` is lightblue for all `Met`.

I am getting close with

```
level2_colors = {
    "Met": "blue",
    "Compensates": "purple",
    "Planned": "#AACC96",
    "To Do": "orange"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(xdata, columns=['Area', 'Status', 'Value'])

fig = px.sunburst(df.assign(hole=" "),
                  path=['hole','Area', 'Status'],
                  values='Value',
                  color_discrete_map=level2_colors
                  )
```

but this approach turns all level 1 segments and the hole into the same color.  Attempts to keep the white hole and randomize level 1 segments breaks the coloring consistency at level 2.  Additionally, I would like all labels to be radially oriented.   I am not wed to `express` and happy to use the lower-level `plotly` SDK.   Suggestions?  This is plotly v5.16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use [`color_discrete_map`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.sunburst.html) for the level 2 segments (Status), you need to set `color='Status'`

> Keys in `color_discrete_map` should be values in the column denoted by
> `color`.

Now all other sectors (non-level2, including root) will have the same color, which we don't want. Though, we can override that color using the special key `"(?)"` in the color map (doesn't help much as it will affects all remaining sectors, but we can still use it to set the root color, knowing we are about to override the level1 segments).

For the level 1 (Area) colors, we can choose a suitably large palette from `px.colors` (see [Discrete Colors](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/)) and do the assignment manually afterwards (once `fig` is created) :

```py
level2_colors = {
    "(?)": "white",          # assign "white" to all remaining sectors, including root
    "Met": "blue",
    "Compensates": "purple",
    "Planned": "#AACC96",
    "To Do": "orange",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(xdata, columns=['Area', 'Status', 'Value'])

fig = px.sunburst(df.assign(hole=" "),
                  path=['hole','Area', 'Status'],
                  values='Value',
                  color='Status',
                  color_discrete_map=level2_colors,
                  )

# Each sector id has its own color
colors = list(fig.data[0]['marker']['colors'])
ids = fig.data[0]['ids']
# print(list(zip(ids, colors)))

areas = df['Area'].unique()
palette = px.colors.qualitative.T10.copy()

# Reset color for each area
for i, id in enumerate(fig.data[0]['ids']):
    if id.split('/')[-1] in areas:
        colors[i] = palette.pop(0)

fig.data[0]['marker']['colors'] = colors
```

And for all labels to be radially oriented, just add :

```py
fig.update_traces(insidetextorientation='radial')
```

---

While playing around with the special key in the color map `"(?)"`, I found a trick to make plotly automagically assign distinct colors from the default palette to those remaining sectors, according to the loaded [template](https://plotly.com/python/templates/) (strangely, setting an array of colors to be mapped to those sectors doesn't work as intended, it behaves the same as setting an empty array, or an empty string, anyway it does the job by picking colors from the template) :

```py
level2_colors = {
    # "(?)": "white",               # assigns "white" to all remaining sectors
    # "(?)": ["white", 'red', ...], # doesn't do what we'd expect (same as below) 
    "(?)": "",                      # assigns distinct colors from template
    "Met": "blue",
    "Compensates": "purple",
    "Planned": "#AACC96",
    "To Do": "orange",
}

df = pd.DataFrame(xdata, columns=['Area', 'Status', 'Value'])

fig = px.sunburst(df.assign(hole=" "),
                  path=['hole','Area', 'Status'],
                  values='Value',
                  color='Status',
                  color_discrete_map=level2_colors,
                  template='seaborn'
                  )
```

Comment: `"(?)": ""` is in fact a great trick.